# Sort cmd not treating same file whether bash script or terminal

Tags: bash, sorting, unix, command-line, terminal

i need to sort some data in order to compare them. I use the command sort. 
When it's use in a terminal it works well but when i use it in a script it reduces the file.

---

size of the dbs :

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache 10646 24 juil. 16:43 db1.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache 10664 24 juil. 16:43 db2.txt
```

directly in the terminal

```
sort db1.txt > db1sorted.txt
sort db2.txt > db2sorted.txt
```

gives

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache 10646 24 juil. 16:06 db1sorted.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache 10664 24 juil. 16:06 db2sorted.txt
```

---

While with the following script (of course input are db1.txt and db2.txt ):

```
FILE1=$1
FILE2=$2
sort ${FILE1} > db1sortedd.txt
sort ${FILE2} > db2sortedd.txt
```

gives

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache 10646 24 juil. 17:01 db1sortedd.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache  8193 24 juil. 17:01 db2sortedd.txt
```

I don't understand why the db2sortedd is smaller with the script than with the terminal. Data are disapearing from the letter s.

Thank You in advance for your help

As suggested i tried with smaller files ( 10 lines ) and it works well.
So it's working for small files but not for big one...

Comment: Can you reproduce with different/smaller files? Ideally so small that you could show the content here.